# Peak splitting in one-component reaction–diffusion equations

Tags: diffusion, solitons

I am studying a one-component reaction–diffusion equation:
$$ \partial_t u(x,t) = D \partial^2_x u(x,t) + R\left(u(x,t)\right)$$
Looking at systems that exhibit a peak solution (solitary localized structures) - are there known general conditions for peak splitting?

Comment: I don't see how this can be approached even without definition of $R$.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know whether there are conditions for R such that there is this possibility. In general I am looking at reaction-diffusion equations where the R is a modified logistic growth term...